# How to pass time.DateTimeExpression or geo.LocalityName to value set on on-click in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I need to pass few values to goal when I am clicking on my `cell-card` but it is not passing. However, Normal values are passing but those who are structure are not passing. I am giving user a `cell-card` which has "What is the sports news for the next week". So my sports is category and next week is `DateTimeExpression`.

So i am able to pass category but not time.
Here is my onclick

```
on-click{
   intent{
     goal:NewsSearch
       value-set:CategoryName{CategoryName(Sports)}
       value-set:MyDateTimeExpression($expr(viv.time.DateTimeExpression(Next Week)))
   }
}
```

My structure `MyDateTimeExpression` is

```
structure (MyDateTimeExpression) {
 role-of(time.DateTimeExpression)
   features {
    transient
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was using `(` instead of `{` when enclosing `MyDateTimeExpression`.

The code below is modified to reflect the correct usage of value-set

```
on-click{
       intent{
         goal:NewsSearch
           value-set:CategoryName{CategoryName(Sports)}
           value-set:MyDateTimeExpression{$expr(nextWeek)}
       }
    }
```

You can take a look at the documentation for more examples of using value and value-set

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/intent.value
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/intent.value-set

Comment: Now it is giving me error: Could not compile expression `viv.time.DateTimeExpression(Next Week)`

Comment: The snippet of code was meant to illustrate how value-set should be used. To get around the error you are seeing, you will need to pass in a input of type MyDateTimeExpression. I will change the answer to reflect that. 

Also note that the conversion of phrases like 'next weekend', 'next month' is not available outside of training. i.e. Bixby will convert these phrases when used in training and fill in the appropriate input type (Date, DateTime, etc) in your Action but there is no way for developers to do the same inside of the capsule.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Natural Language inside a button, then perhaps you should try using a [conversation-driver](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.conversation-drivers) instead of a `cell-card`. This has the advantage that it will work not just via the button press, but also in hands-free mode if the user speaks out the request.

Inside your result-view, you would add a block like this:

```
  conversation-drivers {
    conversation-driver {
      template ("What is the sports news for the next week.")
    }
  }
```

And you would train similar utterances in the training tab. The aligned-nl in the source view would look something like this:

```
[g:NewsSearch] What are the (sports)[v:CategoryName:Sports] news for (next week)[v:time.DateTimeExpression]
```